# Calling Sub to all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. I have been researching past codes to help me build my own.

my problem is that sub1 and sub2 work perfectly on their own. Sub1 goes through all the worksheets in the workbook while sub2 only works on the active workbook. Therefore, as I loop through the worksheets in sub1, I want to call sub2. The two subs are not related and therefore I do not have any inputs to use from sub1 to sub2.

```
Sub titles()
Dim titles() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook


titles() = Array("Distance", "Count", "Fe %", "Cr %", "Fe (Mean)", "Fe (std)", "Cr (Mean)", "Cr(std)", "x", "Fe", "x", "Cr", "x", "Fe", "x", "Cr", "Fe W", "Fe A", "Cr W", "Cr A")

For Each ws In wb.Sheets

    With ws
    For i = 41 + LBound(titles()) To 41 + UBound(titles())

        .Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = titles(i - 41)

    Next i

    End With

 **Formulas ws**



Next ws


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub



**Public Sub Formulas(ws As Worksheet)**

**With ws**


   Dim R As Long
   Dim OutR1   As Long, OutR2 As Long, outRow As Long
   Dim MaxRow1 As Long, MaxRow2 As Long
   Dim SeriesFlag As Integer



   Range(Cells(2, "AX"), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, "BE")).ClearContents

   R = 2

   outRow = 2

    Do Until Cells(R, "AP") = ""


   MaxRow1 = NextMaximumRow(R:=R, DataCol:=Range("AR1").Column, WMean:=Range("AT2"), WSErr:=Range("AU2"))


   If MaxRow1 > 0 Then

   Cells(outRow, Range("AX1").Column) = Cells(MaxRow1, "AP") ' x
   Cells(outRow, Range("AY1").Column) = Cells(MaxRow1, Range("AR1").Column)       ' y

   Cells(outRow, Range("AZ1").Column) = Cells(MaxRow1, "AP") ' x
   Cells(outRow, Range("BA1").Column) = 0       ' y

   R = R + 1

   outRow = outRow + 1
   End If



  If MaxRow1 = 0 Then
   R = R + 1
  End If



   R = R + 1

   Loop


   R = 2

   Do Until Cells(R, "AP") = ""



    MaxRow2 = NextMaximumRow(R:=R, DataCol:=Range("AS1").Column, WMean:=Range("AV2"), WSErr:=Range("AW2"))


    If MaxRow2 > 0 Then


   Cells(outRow, Range("AZ1").Column) = Cells(MaxRow2, "AP") ' x
   Cells(outRow, Range("BA1").Column) = Cells(MaxRow2, Range("AS1").Column)       ' y
   Cells(outRow, Range("AX1").Column) = Cells(MaxRow2, "AP") ' x
   Cells(outRow, Range("AY1").Column) = 0       ' y


    R = R + 1

   outRow = outRow + 1
   End If


  If MaxRow2 = 0 Then
   R = R + 1
  End If


   R = R + 1

   Loop

 Call Range("AX:BA").Sort(Key1:=Range("AX1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes)


 R = 2
 OutR1 = 2
 OutR2 = 2

 Dim PeakRow1 As Long, PeakRow2 As Long

  ' Which series has the first Peak?


   PeakRow1 = NextPeakRow(R:=2, DataCol:=Range("AY1").Column)

   PeakRow2 = NextPeakRow(R:=2, DataCol:=Range("BA1").Column)

   If PeakRow1 < PeakRow2 And PeakRow1 > 0 Then
      Cells(OutR1, Range("BB1").Column) = Cells(PeakRow1, "AX") ' x
      Cells(OutR1, Range("BC1").Column) = Cells(PeakRow1, Range("AY1").Column)         ' y
      OutR1 = OutR1 + 1
      SeriesFlag = 2 ' next series to check
      R = PeakRow1

   ElseIf PeakRow2 > 0 Then
      Cells(OutR2, Range("BD1").Column) = Cells(PeakRow2, "AX") ' x
      Cells(OutR2, Range("BE1").Column) = Cells(PeakRow2, Range("BA1").Column)         ' y
      OutR2 = OutR2 + 1
      SeriesFlag = 1 ' next series to check
      R = PeakRow2

    ElseIf PeakRow2 = 0 Then
    SeriesFlag = 1
    R = PeakRow2 + 1

    ElseIf PeakRow1 = 0 Then
    SeriesFlag = 2
    R = PeakRow1 + 1

   Else
      MsgBox "There is no Peak"
      Exit Sub
   End If

   R = R + 1

   Do Until Cells(R, "AP") = ""

      Select Case SeriesFlag

         Case 1

            PeakRow1 = NextPeakRow(R:=R, DataCol:=Range("AY1").Column)
            If PeakRow1 > 0 Then
      Cells(OutR1, Range("BB1").Column) = Cells(PeakRow1, "AX") ' x
      Cells(OutR1, Range("BC1").Column) = Cells(PeakRow1, Range("AY1").Column)         ' y
      OutR1 = OutR1 + 1
      SeriesFlag = 2
      R = PeakRow1

            End If

         Case 2

            PeakRow2 = NextPeakRow(R:=R, DataCol:=Range("BA1").Column)
           If PeakRow2 > 0 Then
      Cells(OutR2, Range("BD1").Column) = Cells(PeakRow2, "AX") ' x
      Cells(OutR2, Range("BE1").Column) = Cells(PeakRow2, Range("BA1").Column)         ' y
      OutR2 = OutR2 + 1
      SeriesFlag = 1 ' next series to check
      R = PeakRow2

            End If

         Case Else
            Stop

      End Select

      R = R + 1

   Loop

 **End With**

 End Sub
```

Comment: Please post your formulas() sub.

Comment: Your `titles` subroutine never changes the active worksheet.  (Which is **good**!)  So how will your `Formulas` subroutine know which worksheet to use if you don't pass that as a parameter?  (This comment is predicated on the assumption that "while sub2 only works on the active **workbook**" really means "while sub2 only works on the active **worksheet**".)

Comment: And the syntax to call a subroutine is just `Call Formulas`, or `Formulas`, (or `Call Formulas(parm1, parm2, etc)`, or `Formulas parm1, parm2, etc`) not `Call Sub Formulas()`.

Comment: I realize that I would need to call back the sub titles() inside the sub formulas in order to go to the next active worksheet. Is that what you mean. I have tried that by putting Call titles at the end of my long formulas sub, but excel froze. please help

Comment: Yes, I tried Call Formulas and Formulas...

Comment: No, at the end of `Formulas` control would automatically return to `titles` - you don't have to call it.

Comment: Post your `Formulas` code and we can help you fix things.  (Or at least the top part of it if it is too long to post all of it.)

Comment: Both ways still not working to call the sub to do the formulas in all the worksheets. It only does works in the current one that is active.

Comment: As I said in my first comment, you are never changing the "active" sheet, so if your `formulas` subroutine works on `ActiveSheet` then it will always be working on the same sheet.

Comment: Or see Chris' answer for a "template" of what you need.

Comment: will post shortly, excel keeps crashing now

Comment: How do I stop excel from freezing? I have not saved my work, so I do not want to stop process at the task manager.

Comment: at the time being, where is Chris' answer

Comment: Ok, I see Chris' code. Will try it later. I will wait for excel to operate normally first. I do not know how long it will take.

Comment: If `Formulas` is calling `titles` which is calling `Formulas` which is calling `titles` ..., I think it may take some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General structure you need is

```
Sub Sub1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        ' other code
        Sub2 ws
    Next
End Sub

Sub Sub2(ws as Worksheet)
    ' work with ws object
    ' eg
    With ws
        .Cells(11, 1).Formula = "=Sum(A1:A10)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I am running into other problems, which I think is related to the With ws loop. If I am calling another Sub3 within Sub2, do I have to change all Cells into .Cells formatting? The reason I ask is that in Sub1, I called Sub2 without any inputs. However, I have inputs when I call Sub3 within Sub2, so I do not know how to show that. Sub1 is titles(), Sub2 is formulas(ws as Worksheet), Sub3 is NextPeakRow(R As Long, DataCol As Long) As Long. So, do I have to change it to: NextPeakRow(R As Long, DataCol As Long, ws as Worksheet) As Long?

Comment: I tried the above: NextPeakRow(R As Long, DataCol As Long, ws as Worksheet) As Long with the .Cells and .Range formatting and With ws loop inside the Sub. It is not working, I am getting a Compile Error: Argument not optional

Comment: I am very confused on the syntax. When I call Sub2 within Sub1, I just wrote a line: 'formulas ws'. However, when i call Sub3 within Sub2, it is in the form of a formula: 'PeakRow1 = NextPeakRow(R:=2, DataCol:=.Range("AY1").Column)'. So, where would I put the ws? Please help me with this, I have been researching and I cannot find a way.

Comment: @Sarah if you are calling Sub3 like that it must actually be a Function.  Functions also can have parameters, so it's declaration would be something like `Function Sub3(ws As Worksheet) As SomeType` and would be called like `SomeVariable = Sub3(ws)`

Comment: Yes, the sub3 is a private function. Is this ok: 'Private Function NextPeakRow(R As Long, DataCol As Long, ws As Worksheet) As Long', which would be called like: 'PeakRow1 = NextPeakRow(R:=2, DataCol:=.Range("AY1").Column, ws)'

Comment: Try using `PeakRow1 = NextPeakRow(2, .Range("AY1").Column, ws)`